# problem with date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$usr_profile->getCreatedAt()) getting error?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to parse my MYSQL date in to the format Y-m-d H:i:s and get error:

```
 //theses lines ok
 echo $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'])."<br/>";
 echo $nowday = date('d',$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'])."<br/>";
 echo $nowmonth = date('m',$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'])."<br/>";


 echo $userdate =  $usr_profile->getCreatedAt()."<br/>";
 echo $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$userdate)."<br/>";  //line 67 error
 echo $usermonth = date('m',$newdate)."<br/>";   //line 68 error



2011-01-21 08:44:07
```

Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/plugins/rainbowCodePlugin/modules/profile/templates/homeSuccess.php on line 67 1970-01-01 00:33:31
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/helloises/github_mira/rainbow_code/phoenix/plugins/rainbowCodePlugin/modules/profile/templates/homeSuccess.php on line 68 01

i dont understand... i need to check if the difference between two dates (now and userdate) is greater than 24 hours
i tried a few things like strtotime, create_date,format_date, DateTime() but to now avail
please help?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping `$newdate` in `strtotime`:

```
$newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($userdate))."<br/>"
```

Comment: echo $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($userdate))."<br/>"; gives me:  1970-01-01 00:00:00  which is not the date in my database field?? i should get: 2011-01-21 08:44:07 and if i do: echo $userday = date('d',$newdate)."<br/>"; i must get 21..please help? thank you

Comment: Can you `var_dump($userdate)` and post back the entire output from this function.

Comment: $userdate =  $usr_profile->getCreatedAt()."<br/>";
var_dump($userdate)."<br/>"; gives: string(24) "2011-01-21 08:44:07"

Comment: i work in php php: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9 and symfony 1.4.2 can this be the issue?